# Detecting if a moving UIImageView has been touched

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I have a `UIImageView` which is in an animation loop. I want to detect if it has been touched and print out a message with `NSLog`. The idea will be to perform another animation if it has been touched, but for the moment i can't detect if it has been touched in the first place. User interaction has been enabled. Here is the code:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView *touchedView = [touch view];
    if (touchedView == imgSun) {
        NSLog(@"Sun touched");
        [self spinSun];
    } else if (touchedView == imgBee) {
        NSLog(@"Bee touched");
    } else if (touchedView == imgClouds) {
        NSLog(@"Clouds touched");
    }
}
```

The animation method:

```
-(void) beeBobbing
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat) animations:^{
        CGPoint bottomPoint = CGPointMake(215.0, 380.0);
        imgBee.center = bottomPoint;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];    
}
```

Comment: Are you subclassing the UIImageView? Because else you cannot access the touchesBegan delegate method. Also, why don't you simply use UIGestureRecongizers?

Comment: Another way to do this would be to use a custom button and put the image as the background image for this button,then u can easily understand if it is touched

Comment: I'm very new to programming and haven't used UIGestureRecognizers before. Having used touches began beofre i decided to do it this way. The below answer seems to be working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because user integration is disabled by default during an animation.

See animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: documentation:

During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for the views being animated. (Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are disabled for the entire application.) If you want users to be able to interact with the views, include the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction constant in the options parameter.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

You can probability just add UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction to the value passed to options in your method 'beeBobbing'.

Comment: @garethdn: you should accept J_D's answer if it's working - and it should work :)